# Is it possible for start and auction and bid for multiple names(ENS) in a single transaction?

Tags: ens, auctions

For example if I want to register three TLD domains:

example1.eth

example2.eth

example3.eth

Can I make one startAuctionAndBid transaction for all three?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I make one startAuctionAndBid transaction for all three?

Yes, but it's called `startAuctionsAndBid` (note the extra `s`):

Here is the [Solidity version of the contract method](https://github.com/ensdomains/ens/blob/9f0dc10c2b7ff73c1c3c921219a5e52083010a79/contracts/HashRegistrar.sol#L141), as a reference for how to use it:

```
/**
 * @dev Start a set of auctions and bid on one of them
 *
 * This method functions identically to calling `startAuctions` followed by `newBid`,
 * but all in one transaction.
 *
 * @param hashes A list of hashes to start auctions on.
 * @param sealedBid A sealed bid for one of the auctions.
 */
function startAuctionsAndBid(bytes32[] hashes, bytes32 sealedBid) public payable {
    startAuctions(hashes);
    newBid(sealedBid);
}
```